# Android studio unable to build my app after gradle plugin updated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I updated the Gradle plugin yesterday and now the android studio is not able to build my app. The app shows the following error.

```
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.16.1].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.16.1].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.16.1].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.16.1].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.16.1].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app
```

My app level build.gradle file looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mvp1stockmeter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding
            {
                enabled true
            }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.x'

    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project level build.gradle file looks like this:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I searched this on StackOverflow and google as well. But did not find any information. Please help. I am stuck here.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: Bintray is having issues in downloading. You can check its status here... https://status.bintray.com/

Comment: probably related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276279/unable-to-get-kotlin-pom-from-jcenter-with-a-new-project/55277519

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a clue why this is happening, but it is happening since yesterday, March 21 2019. I think it is a problem in the maven repository? Because the url where android studio is trying to get that library is down.

Anyway, the fix is to "manually" point AS to that missing dependency, adding this line into your build.gradle, inside dependencies{...}

```
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-core', version: '1.16.1'
```

Then sync, then you can delete that line.

Well, I hope someone can explain what happened.

Answer (score 6):

Adding mavenCentral() to allprojects{} section of project level build.gradle file has resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

Adding mavenCentral() to buildScript{} section of project level build.gradle file has resolved this issue for me. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I had three build errors of the following type:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.28.0].
```

As with many of these android studio related issues,

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line :- testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"...It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Add mavenCentral() to your buildscripts->repositories and allprojects->repositories both places and sync the project.