# Unable to get dependencies from jcenter with a new project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I'm unable to get kotlin pom from jcenter with a new project.

All I have done is gone File->New Project and created a new project with no activity.

I'm getting the following error when it tries to build:

```
ERROR: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

My build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I go in my web browser to that URL I can't connect either. https://jcenter.bintray.com/

Does this mean the site is temporarily down or is there something I need to add to my build files?

BTW I selected Java for the project and not Kotlin on setup if that matters so not even sure why it's trying to get kotlin stuff.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well and thought it was very weird. Since I'm not the only one, I'm thinking it may be temporary

Comment: maybe we should not upgrade the gradle to 3.3.2 yet

Answer (score 19, accepted):

jcenter is currently down. In the end adding `mavenCentral()` to both sets of repositories in the **project** `build.gradle` file worked as a workaround for me:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
```

...

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() 
        google() 
        jcenter()
```

...

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: @MateenSheikh , do you still get the same error? What does your build file look like?

Comment: @user8810083 jcenter is working fine now so issue is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade Gradle version is not a good fix for me. I did google around and found this. Jcenter is dead. For now.

https://status.bintray.com/?fbclid=IwAR3NLsnuGA5xqbFhcPsVLWX2c9TG40JWQcDYM7RTVsDm0qDSQvfjmhabhPg

I think all we can do is wait.

Comment: see the answer I just posted. Just adding mavenCentral() to both sets of repositories works for me now

Comment: The server is broken! I did a completely fresh install of android studio and can't create a new project

Comment: @Benjamin , adding mavenCentral as repository is a workaround for now

Answer (score 4):

While mostly meant as a temporary, change-back-again-when-jcenter-is-working solution, this can be fixed by downgrading the gradle plugin version to 3.3.1 in the project's gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

Comment: @Chisko I'm still getting the same error as OP

Comment: this didn't work for me, but see the answer I just posted. Just adding mavenCentral() to both sets of repositories works for me now

Comment: this gives me a read timeout error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in `Downloads` section with `Partial Outage` in jfrog bintray (https://status.bintray.com/incidents/2wvx6d5f807c):

> Intermittent download issues in Bintray

You can see the current status in https://status.bintray.com/

---

Update Status from jfrog Bintray:

```
Update - There are still intermittent download issues in Oregon region (north America). We are still working on identifying the root cause. 
Mar 21, 10:02 UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

replace jcenter() with   mavenCentral()
because jcenter is not available now

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `dependencies` block

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
```

Comment: Maybe the OP doesn't need Kotlin support

Answer (score 1):

Actually android studio already had the solution for you :

Syncing only active variant
You can disable this experimental feature from
File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant

Answer (score 0):

To fix it open android sdk manager and:

1.Uninstall android support repository
 2.Install again android support repository
 3.clean project and rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

It's 3 days later and i was still getting random 502 errors from bintray, for links that seemed perfectly valid. Manually checking with browser / curl the pom files were there.

What eventually helped get around, was slowing gradle down by not letting it hit the links all at once. In my case, cordova/ionic project, so

```
ionic cordova run android -- -- --gradleArg=--max-workers=1
```

Passing `--no-parallel` should work as well