# Android Gradle build error - artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, nativescript

I'm getting the errors below, when running the command `tns run android` or `tns debug android`. Before it was working fine until I've deleted `.gradle/gradle.properties` folder from the `C:\Users\yash\.gradle\gradle.properties` and now I'm not able to UNDO it.

There 1 of the 50 error I'm getting is:

> ```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0.
>      Required by:
>          project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1
>          project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.1
>          project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02
> ```

**Version of NS**

```
 "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.chennaivolunteers",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.2.1"
    }
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
...

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

android {
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "org.nativescript.chennaivolunteers"  
  }  
  signingConfigs {
    config {
      // You need to specify either an absolute path or include the
      // keystore file in the same directory as the build.gradle file.
      storeFile file("<store-filename>.jks")
      storePassword "<store-password>"
      keyAlias "<store-alias>"
      keyPassword "<store-password>"
    }
  }
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
} 
project.ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
...
```

Comment: This probably related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276279/unable-to-get-kotlin-pom-from-jcenter-with-a-new-project/55277519

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by changing quite a few things in my `app.gradle` 
I have added `mavenCentral()` and changed the version number to `3.3.1` from `3.3.0` `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bintray is download issues on their network https://status.bintray.com/
[image]