# .ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.3

after working on an old source code ...i upgraded everything from sdk to gradle but when i rebuilt the project i got ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()' please help

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278227/android-gradle-build-error-artifacts-for-configuration-classpath?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle build error - artifacts for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278227/android-gradle-build-error-artifacts-for-configuration-classpath)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google)