# Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I am developing an Android app for mobile, however when I create a new any project in Android Studio. I have got this error. I spent more time to surface on the internet. but have no result.

Detail of log is as below:

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.72/kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.pom'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to get dependencies from jcenter with a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276279/unable-to-get-dependencies-from-jcenter-with-a-new-project)

Comment: I tried to fix with some suggestion, but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

Just replace this and sync the project.